# Linux driver writing, file_operations incompatible pointer type errror

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a simple linux driver which would accept messages piped thru CLI and I am getting an incompatible pointer type error.

My read function and file_operations struct:

```
ssize_t driver_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, ssize_t len, loff_t *offset) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Write: %s\n", message);
    return 0;
}

struct file_operations fops = {
    write: driver_write,
    read: driver_read
};
```

When I try to compile the code I get the following error:

```
error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 read: driver_read
```

According to another post here, the return type of the read function should be ssize_t, which I have, but I am still getting this error.

Comment: I think `ssize_t len` should be `size_t len`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the prototype's parameter to this:

```
ssize_t len
```

to this:

```
size_t len
```

[Source](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch03s08.html)